# How to click icon within pop-up in Selenium webdriver using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to close credit card 3DS verification by clicking the 'X' icon at the top right of the pop-up as below.

[image: 3DS Pop-up]

CSS code for above pop-up is here:

```
<div id="three-ds-container" style="">
        <i id="close-3ds" style="position: absolute;right: 10px;top: 10px;cursor:pointer;" class="fa fa-close"></i>
        <iframe height="450" width="550" id="sample-inline-frame" name="sample-inline-frame"></iframe>
    </div>
```

I tried to click the icon by using

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#three-ds-container i#close-3ds.fa.fa-close').click()
```

but the pop-up won't close.

I noticed that when I hover my mouse over the icon, the cursor will give indication that the icon can be clicked, is it related to my problem?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you share the url to be crawled ?

Comment: @anon_143 I'm sorry I'm afraid I can't do that at this time since it's related to payment process in my software company

Comment: is it closing when you click it manually? please check the button is inside iframe and  are you getting any exception when you click it?  wait for some times before clicking.

Comment: It's ok I would suggest you to use xpath if css selector isn't working or any other random site you know which has a popup like this ?

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#three-ds-container > i.fa-close#close-3ds"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='three-ds-container']/i[@class='fa fa-close' and @id='close-3ds']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The popup is in a different frame than you are, so I believe your issue is that you need to switch to that frame (iframe height="450" width="550" id="sample-inline-frame" name="sample-inline-frame")in order to click the close button.

The code to do this would look something like this:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("sample-inline-frame")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#three-ds-container i#close-3ds.fa.fa-close').click()
```

I ran into the same issue previously, so I know the frustration, hope this helps.